How to prevent a Power Bi measure to split over months?
I have a measure that calculates the open orders value up to today.
In the visuals, I want to show this value in the current month.
Power BI splits the values over the months, based on the order date.
Is there a way to prevent this split over the months based on the order date, but only show the total value (so sum of all the previous months) in the current month?

I solved it by creating an aggregated table with a date column = today() and used the columns of that table in the measure. Result is that all open orders are shown on today's date.
